# Equivalent to not separable?

Tags: functional-analysis

I wanted to ask if this statement is true,

Let $X$ be a normed vectorspace.

Then,

X is separable iff every disjoint, and open familiy of subsets is countable.

My idea to prove it was the following,

$"\Rightarrow"$

Assume for contradiction that there exists $(A_i)_{i\in I}\subset\mathcal P(X)$ where $A_i$ is open for every $i\in I$ and $A_i\bigcap A_j=\emptyset\;\forall i\neq j $ and $I$ is uncountable.

But then since by assumption $X$ is seperable there exist $Q\subset X$ s.t $Q$ is countable and $Q$ is dense in X. This implies that $A_i\bigcap G\neq\emptyset,\;\;\forall i\in I$. Since $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ is disjoint we could construct a surjection,
$$\phi:G\rightarrow(A_i)_{i\in I}$$
which is absurd.

I am not sure if the other direction also is true, could someone help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: "every disjoint, uncountable and open familiy of subsets is countable" - how can the family be both countable and uncountable?

Comment: "every disjoint, uncountable and open familiy of subsets is countable." This sentence is... strange.

Comment: @user2357112 Tahnks i just edited the post

Comment: @5xum I also had to correct it in the proof, $I$ is also uncountable! sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Forward is easy; take a countable, dense subset B of A, and for any family of disjoint open sets in A, take a point in B from every member of the family. Then the chosen points must be countable, so the family must be countable. No assumption about I being uncountable is necessary.

Comment: Yes, you are right! thanks!

Comment: ...and I misread. You're going for a proof by contradiction, so the assumption about I being uncountable makes sense. I got mixed up by the earlier nonsensical line about the family being both uncountable and countable.